# Can i embed an image on my asp send mail?

Tags: asp-classic

i have a client that has old school asp. Is it possible to edit the asp file to embeded an image? i only have the asp file and inside that asp file it has an auto response form like this

```
body = "Dear " & cName & "," & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "Your request for the " & vehHeader & " (" & FormatCurrency(vehPrice)& ")" & " has been received and will be reviewed promptly." & vbcrlf & "We will contact you shortly to verify your information." & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "Thank you for using ClassicShowcase.com."
AppSendMail AppSupportMailto, cEMail, "Confirmation of vehicle request...", body
AppReportError "CUBid.asp: Error sending confirmation e-mail."

AppSendMail AppSupportMailto, AppSupportMailto, "Web bid for the " & vehHeader, "Check Administration Center for details."
AppReportError "CUBid.asp: Error sending confirmation e-mail."
```

i do not have the VB files or the solution file how would i be able to embed images from the server so when the user gets the auto response email he can view some images

Comment: the body variable is what is going to be shown on the email sent to the requestant

Comment: Do you want to have an image in the body or do you want to have an image attached to the email?

Comment: I want it in the body of the email

Answer (score 2):

Yes, sure, if the app you are using can send HTML in the body you only need to add the image in the body

```
 <body>
     <h1>Hello World</h1>
     I'm sending you this postcard:
     <img src="http://yourdomain.com/images/yourimage.jpg" alt="postcard" />
 </body>
```

Important thing:

- Always add the full path to the image since the email will be opened outside your site

Answer (score -1):

Eduardo (love the pic!) is right.  And the full URL to the image is critical!